# Check if a recursive type ends with a certain type

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation, recursive-type

I have the following type definition in Typescript:

```
type MU = ['I' | 'U' | 'M', MU] | '.'
```

And I'm trying to write the helper:

```
type EndsWith<T extends MU, M extends MU> = T extends M ? any : T extends [infer _, infer Q] ? EndsWith<Q, M> : never
```

Which would check if a specific type `T` ends with a given `M`, *i.e.*:

```
const a: EndsWith<['U', ['I', '.']], ['I', '.']>  // types as any
const b: EndsWith<['U', '.'], ['I', '.']>         // types as never
```

However, `EndsWith` is not an aliased type in the way I am specifying it. Looking for a workaround :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular conditional types are not currently supported.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) for an open issue suggesting that this constraint be lifted.  For now, they are forbidden.

---

Note that it is quite possible to *trick* the compiler into evaluating circular conditional types, but if you do that and it behaves badly, it's your problem and not TypeScript's.

Here's one such trick.  It is [not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373):

```
type EndsWith<T extends MU, M extends MU> =
    T extends M ? any :
    {
        base: never,
        step: EndsWith<T extends any[] ? T[1] : never, M>
    }[T extends '.' ? "base" : "step"];
```

What we've done is to turn your obviously circular type into a recursive, tree-like object that we immediately index down into with a deferred conditional type.  That's still circular, but the compiler doesn't notice it.

It "works":

```
declare const a: EndsWith<['U', ['I', '.']], ['I', '.']>  // any
declare const b: EndsWith<['U', '.'], ['I', '.']>         // never
```

but is fragile.  If you write this:

```
declare const c: EndsWith<MU, ['I', MU]>  // oops
```

you are asking the compiler to evaluate `EndsWith<MU, ['I', MU]>` by first checking if `MU extends ['I', MU]` (it doesn't), and then recursing down into... `EndsWith<MU, ['I', MU]>` again.  Uh oh.  There will be a compiler problem somewhere; most likely you'll get a "this type is too deeply instantiated error.  If you're really clever you can probably write some code using the above `EndsWith` that will actually cause the compiler to hang instead of spitting out an error.

I get the sense that you're just writing `EndsWith` for academic purposes (since lists implemented as cons-like pairs is not idiomatic JS or TS) so maybe the fact that it's unsupported isn't a problem.  If I'm wrong and you want this for production code somewhere, *please don't*.  I don't want to be an accessory to crimes against the compiler.

Hope that helps; good luck!  [Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgqlAvFA2gcgJJqgHymubPNGNAGljgF1d8A6NAWACgXRIoBRAOwBMBnAOoBLYAAsAPABUoEAB7AIffpQoxZCpQMoA+JCyiGoM+YuWwoAfigBDbiCgAuA0YDeLo0YBGN-hEdQ3BAAbhAAThQenlD8imABPAIi4tIaZtp2ICg01lIoAIw0AUGhEbA6UQC+KCaa5mgMVlAARD5+zU4tsRBgzVQA3CwsvBAAxgA2NmHQowD23LG2CcrJkuiEFOhYFA1oVFSbmOT0e3pQAPTntvbDY5PTUHMLwFBey0miawTHuweoRzsGFQztFDJdAiFwkNmOCAK7cOYAW0RShe4mgQQUUHGwiCUAAZrMwgT4SxwSMJlMZvNFqN3kJPhJ4IdtpRgVAgA)

Comment: _"I don't want to be an accessory to crimes against the compiler"_ is probably the best expression I have ever read for dissuading type-level tricks to transform into some poor young developer's maintenance nightmare :-) Don't worry, I'm just trying to figure out how much I can stretch the type system.